# Format the technical date to user understandable in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
  time : "2016-04-30T21" 
}
```

Need to format the date user understandable.

**Expected output:**

```
{
  time: 21h 30.04.2016
}
```

Comment: why not format on the client side (nodejs/js)?

Comment: I have to format in MongoDB, not using nodejs/js

Comment: yes i know that, why you want to do this in mongodb query, at the end it is showing in client side.

Comment: I am making the microservice, from the DB user to get the understandable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$dateFromString` to convert date to date type from string
- `$dateToString` convert above converted date to specific format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      time: {
        "$dateToString": {
          "date": {
            "$dateFromString": {
              "dateString": "$time",
              "format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H"
            }
          },
          "format": "%Hh %d.%m.%Y"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8q0VZsnyj5i)

> **NOTE:**
>
> - It would be easy and fast this conversation in the client-side language (node/js), I would not recommend this date format customization approach in the query because why we add more process time in the query instead we can achieve in client-side in quickly.
> - I would suggest you store this date to date type instead of string type because it will really help to match query and conversation to specific timezone format without any extra operators.